# Toggle class which be clicked in multiple class - DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I try to toggle class when `td` clicked in multiple class but it does not work. I prefer working on DOM.

```js
window.onload = function() {
 var seats = document.getElementsByClassName('seat');

 for(var i = 0; i < seats.length; i++) {
 seats[i].onclick = function() {
   seats[i].classList.toggle = 'selected';
  }
 }
}
```

```css
td {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;}

td.selected {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="seat">1</td>
    <td class="seat">2</td>
    <td class="seat">3</td>
    <td class="seat">4</td>
    <td class="seat">5</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

http://jsbin.com/kufemuhagi/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 3):

**Problem :**

You've a scope problem in the posted code where your variable `i` counldn't found inside the event handler, this variable is accessible just outside of it, to fix this you need to wrap the assignment of the event listener in a closure, like :

```
for (var i = 0; i < seats.length; i++) {
  (function(i) {
    seats[i].onclick = function() {
      seats[i].classList.toggle('selected');
    }
  })(i);
}
```

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var seats = document.getElementsByClassName('seat');

  for (var i = 0; i < seats.length; i++) {
    (function(i) {
      seats[i].onclick = function() {
        console.log(i);
        seats[i].classList.toggle('selected');
      }
    })(i);
  }
}
```

```css
td {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

td.selected {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class="seat">1</td>
      <td class="seat">2</td>
      <td class="seat">3</td>
      <td class="seat">4</td>
      <td class="seat">5</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

**My suggestion :**

Separate you logic and use `addEventListener()` to attach the events, then use `this` to toggle your class, like the sample below shows.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var seats = document.getElementsByClassName('seat');

  var clickHandler = function() {
    this.classList.toggle('selected');
  };

  for (var i = 0; i < seats.length; i++) {
    seats[i].addEventListener('click', clickHandler, false);
  }
}
```

```css
div.selected {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="seat">Div 1</div>
<div class="seat">Div 2</div>
<div class="seat">Div 3</div>
<div class="seat">Div 4</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Problem with your code is that the variable `i` isn't defined per iteration it is defined in the function scope. That means that the `for` loop you have goes trough every element and assigns the `onclick` handler to each "seat" but after the last iteration the `i` variable will be set to an out-of-bounds index since the `for` loop does the `i++` expression after each iteration. The problem is your `onclick` handler refers to the `i` variable, which is set to an out-of-bounds index, so that the `seats[i]` expression returns an `undefined` value. You can fix this by using the `this` statement inside the `onclick` handler or by using the first argument which is the click event. The [click](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/click) event contains a `target` which refers to the clicked [`EventTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget) (this should be your "seat" element).

```js
function handleSeatClick(ev) {
  var seat = ev.target;

  if(seat.classList.contains('selected')){
    seat.classList.remove('selected');
  } else {
    seat.classList.add('selected');
  }
}

window.onload = function() {
  var seats = document.getElementsByClassName('seat');

  for(var i = 0; i < seats.length; i++) {
    seats[i].addEventListener('click', handleSeatClick);
  }
}
```

```css
td {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;}

td.selected {
  background-color: black;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="seat">1</td>
    <td class="seat">2</td>
    <td class="seat">3</td>
    <td class="seat">4</td>
    <td class="seat">5</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Hope this will help.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var seats = document.getElementsByClassName('seat');
  for(var i = 0; i < seats.length; i++) {
    seats[i].onclick = function() {
      this.classList.toggle('selected'); //this will refer current object here and toggle is function 

    }
  }
}
```

```css
td {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;}

td.selected {
  background-color: black;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="seat">1</td>
    <td class="seat">2</td>
    <td class="seat">3</td>
    <td class="seat">4</td>
    <td class="seat">5</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```